# Editing a previous edit

Tags: discussion, edits

I will be the first to admit my use of the English language isn't perfect, yet I do sometimes pick up on other users' bad grammar and go to fix it accordingly (only when I think it wouldn't be immediately clear to who's first language isn't English). I have found recently I have submitted an edit which is only half complete or that it would be better if I changed wording ever so slightly, on these occasions I go back in and make this edit (hoping to get in before the moderators approve it). In the meantime the moderators/reviewers have already approved my previous edit and so I end up submitting a second edit for what ultimately should have been one edit; I accept this potentially an extra 2 points but have seen that one of my recent ones wasn't approved probably due to it being a semi-pointless change (it was a slight clarification of a quote I added from a linked site), personally I'd rather not waste the reviewers time if I'm about to go in and make a minor change.

What I was wondering was whether you could temporarily cancel an update you've submitted? Alternatively would be possible to flag that you've gone back in to fix something you've either broken or changed too much?

(And I look forward to anyone editing the countless grammatical errors I've almost certainly added to this post!)

Comment: Sounds like you should just wait until you're actually finished editing to submit the edit.

Comment: I accept that, but sometimes no matter how many times you re-read what you write seeing it again makes you see "something else"

Comment: Sure, so if this happens every once in a while then it's simply not a problem.  If it's happening a lot then it means you need to take your time and not submit your edit so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

> What I was wondering was whether you could temporarily cancel an
>   update you've submitted?

Nope, you can't cancel a suggested edit you've already proposed.

Just make sure you get it right the first time, and if you still accidentally make a mistake hopefully your suggestion will be rejected or improved by the reviewers in the suggested edits queue.